# Download file from REST Call into HTML5 LocalStorage or Web Accessible Directory

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I have a REST API provided to me by an application vendor where I can "Get" images and Collada files. I would like to store these in HTML5 localStorage or some sort of Web Accessible directory (Azure comes to mind), as the Collada file has references to its images and I need to store them in proximity to each other so the textures(images) display on the Collada file when I render it via three.js. Is it possible, or even good practice, to store images/Collada files (extension type is .DAE), within HTML5 localStorage, or is there another preferred method for getting and storing files from a REST API (i.e. Azure Blob storage)? My current AJAX call for download, which is showing as successful in getting the file is as follows... but it is not storing the file in localStorage:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://therestapi.com/image.png',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = result;
                img.load = function () {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    var data = context.getImageData(x, y, img.width, img.height).data;
                    localStorage.setItem('image', data); // save image data
                };
                console.log("Saved Image");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Failed to download image!");
            }
        })
}
```

I am more than open to an option where I save this to a Web accessible directory (would Azure File Storage/Web Services work?), so I can ensure each user has their own "box" to edit that comes from the template I initially download from my application vendor.

Comment: Not sure about The Best Way™ but [most browsers have a 5MB localStorage capacity](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/). You might want to worry about that instead.

Comment: I considered that, and will consider it again. My files will take up to 2MB. It is still something I am watching and may need to invoke a dropbox type scenario. I believe Chrome limits to 2.5MB.